# Using subcaption package with knitr

Tags: subcaption, knitr

How can I use `subcaption` package in `knitr`, instead of the obsolete `subfig` and `\subfloat`?

Or, maybe, specify additional options with `fig.env = 'subfigure'`? It needed something like this:

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  <code>
\end{subfigure}
```

But using only `fig.env` produces, missing the `{0.3\textwidth}`:

```
\begin{subfigure}[!htb]
  \includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{}
  \caption[]{}
  \label{}
\end{subfigure}
```

Comment: see `fig.subcap` in the documentation: http://yihui.name/knitr/options or http://stackoverflow.com/q/18724254/559676

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [knitr option docs](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) and following it to an [example code](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/067-graphics-options.Rnw), it seems that you'd just redefine the `\subfloat`-command, like this: `\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][need a sub-caption]{\subcaptionbox{#1}{#2}}`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\subfloat}[2][need a sub-caption]{\subcaptionbox{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    <<someChunk,cache=T,echo=F,tidy=F, fig.subcap=c("Subfig1", "Subfig2") , fig.cap="TITLE", out.width='.49\\linewidth'>>=
      x=seq(1:10)
      plot(x,x)
      plot(x,x^2)
    @
\end{document}
```

Although, it might be some other way to actually use an environment instead of a command to display figures, I didn't find any. Yet.

---

Also note that `fig.env` only sets the "parent" environment, like `\begin{figure}`, so it seems that if you want to use `fig.env`, you'd have to do it in separate environments, **something like** this:

```
\begin{figure}
  <<someChunk,cache=T,echo=F,tidy=F, fig.subcap=c("Subfig1", "Subfig2") , fig.cap="TITLE", out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.env=c('subfigure')>>=
    x=seq(1:10)
    plot(x,x)
  @
  <<someChunk,cache=T,echo=F,tidy=F, fig.subcap=c("Subfig1", "Subfig2") , fig.cap="TITLE", out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.env=c('subfigure')>>=
    x=seq(1:10)
    plot(x,x^2)
  @
\end{figure}
```

The latter example won't work, since `subfigure` needs an argument, and I'm not really sure how to do that.